# Generate an array of random floats summing to 1 while fixing a few elements in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have something like below:

`random_array = np.random.random(10)`

`scaled_array = random_array/np.sum(random_array)`

This gives me a nice array with random floats that sum to 1. However, I am trying to take this a step further and do the following:

For example, **fix the 2nd and 5th elements to be 0.04 and 0.09 respectively**, and generate all other elements randomly. But the sum of the whole array still needs to be exactly 1.

Taking one more step, I want to **provide an upper (lower) bound for all/each element(s)**. For example, I still want to fix the 4th element to be 0.09 but ALSO want to force ALL elements to be LESS THAN 0.1. (They will still add up to 1 because I have more than 10 elements.)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the string cutting approach of dirichlet distribution:

```
N=7 # total number of elements in result
d = {2:0.04, 5:0.09} # dictionary with index as key and values
fixed_sum = 0.
result = np.zeros(N) # placeholder numpy array
# Put the fixed elements in their place and calculate their sum
for k,v in d.items():
    result[k] = v
    fixed_sum = fixed_sum + v

remaining_sum = 1 - fixed_sum
# Use dirichlet distribution to get elements which sum to 1.
# Multiply with remaining_sum to get elements which sum to "remaining_sum".
remaining_arr = np.random.default_rng().dirichlet(np.ones(N-len(d)))*remaining_sum 
# Get the index of result where elements are zero.
zero_indx = np.nonzero(result==0)[0]
# Place the elements of remaining_arr  in the result.
result[zero_indx] = remaining_arr
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! One follow-up question though, is there a way to provide an upper bound for all/each element(s)? For example, I still want to fix the 4th element to be 0.09 but ALSO want to force ALL elements to be LESS THAN 0.1. (They will still add up to 1 because I have more than 10 elements)

Comment: Please ask another question, I would be happy to try that. Also if this answer helped you, please accept it as correct one.

Comment: Here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763417/generate-an-array-of-random-floats-summing-to-1-while-fixing-a-few-elements-upp

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values before scaling:

```py
import numpy as np

random_array = np.random.random(10)
random_array[1] = 0.04
random_array[4] = 0.09
scaled_array  = random_array/np.sum(random_array)
assert np.isclose(1, scaled_array.sum())
```

If you want fixed values after scaling:

```py
import numpy as np

random_array = np.random.random(10)
random_array[1] = 0
random_array[4] = 0

scaled_array  = (random_array/np.sum(random_array)) * (1.0 - (0.04 + 0.09))
scaled_array[1] = 0.04
scaled_array[4] = 0.09

assert np.isclose(1, scaled_array.sum())
```

Comment: I think there was confusion in the problem, I actually wanted to make the 4th element to be 0.09 AFTER the scaling.

Comment: I actually added one more part to the question - would there be any way I can set "lower bound"/"upper bound" for some elements?

Comment: As MSS said above, Please ask another question, I would be happy to try that. Also if this answer helped you, please accept it as correct one

Comment: Here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763417/generate-an-array-of-random-floats-summing-to-1-while-fixing-a-few-elements-upp